# How to use this API(HttpConnectionMetrics) in android?

Tags: android, httpclient

I want to get the number of requests send to server and number of responses received from server while loading a web page in android. I found some API's in `HttpConnectionMetrics`

```
getRequestCount(); 
getResponseCount();
```

But i don't know how to use them. Please help me in this with a sample code. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Be a bit more specific, we're not here to just write code for you.

Comment: That class is part of the Apache HttpClient library. You will be better served looking for answers related to HttpClient than you will answers related to Android.